# Does the Open Government Licence impose any restrictions on derivative works?

Tags: copyright, united-kingdom, licensing, government-contracts

Most information made available on the [UK government portal](https://www.gov.uk/) is  under the [Open Government Licence (OGL) v3.0](https://www.nationalarchives.gov.uk/doc/open-government-licence/version/3/).  This states:

You are free to:

- copy, publish, distribute and transmit the Information;
- adapt the Information;
- exploit the Information commercially and non-commercially for example, by combining it with other Information, or by including it in your own product or application.

You must (where you do any of the above):

- acknowledge the source of the Information in your product or application by including or linking to any attribution statement specified by the Information Provider(s) and, where possible, provide a link to this licence;

It does not appear to have an explicit "share alike" clause, which I am aware of from the [CC-SA](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/sa/1.0/) and the [GPL](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-3.0.en.html).

Suppose that Alice took a work covered by the OGL, adapted it creating a derivative work, posted the derivative work online with attribution and a copy of the OGL, and stated that it was made available under the [CC zero licence](https://creativecommons.org/share-your-work/public-domain/cc0/).  Bob took this derivative work and republished it without attribution.  Would either Alice or Bob be in breach of this licence?

Answer (score 2):

### Only Alice’s components would be CC0; all the original components would be OGL

Both Alice and Bob have the benefit of the OGL on all of the original copy. Alice’s changes, additions etc. belong to Alice and she can release those however she likes - subject to the constraints of the OGL if she is distributing both works together.